# Which Android Events do I use for this task?

Tags: java, android, mouse, listener

I have a Java class that pertains to mouse listeners that I'm wanting to convert over to my Android app but can't quite find the necessary events.

My Java app makes use of the following methods:

- mouseClicked
- mousePressed
- mouseReleased

I'm wanting to do something similar however not with click events but touch events. I have come across `OnTouchListener` and did an override on the `onTouch` method.

What are the alternatives to `mousePressed` and `mouseReleased`?

**Edit - (updated after Peter's response)**

Are the following events correct:

- ACTION_DOWN : mouseClicked
- ACTION_MOVE : mousePressed
- ACTION_UP   : mouseReleased

**EDIT - 2 Example Source**

My Activity doesn't have any `OnTouchListener` at the moment because I was hoping I could keep all the touch logic in my View.

View:

```
/*Inside my View - Is it proper to do onTouch logic here? 
                   Or should I be doing this from the Activity?*/

public class myView {

    public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent event) {

        switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //draw arrow when screen is simply touched
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                //Do Logic
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //Do Logic
                break;        

        }

    }
}
```

The reason I am doing the logic in my View is because I have some variables that I would like to grab directly rather than creating multiple extra get methods.

Am I able to do it like this? Or will I have to override the onTouch method in my Activity and do the logic there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to register clicks on a `View`, implement and add an [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) to it.
When you want to register touch events you need to implement the [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) and add it to that `View`.

Comment: Correct, that is what I'm doing. However, I'm looking for which specific events are closest to the three methods in Java. If `ACTION_DOWN` equals `mousePressed`, what would be the equivalent of `mouseClicked`. From my understanding `mouseClicked` would be just tapping the devices screen and `mousePressed` would be until the screen is released (in case the user moves the touch). Does `ACTION_DOWN` account for both `mouseClicked` and `mousePressed`?

Comment: Also, do you suggest creating the `onTouch` method in the View? Or overriding it from the Activity?

Comment: `ACTION_DOWN` does not account for clicked and pressed but for `mousePressed`. The `OnClickListener`is what the `mouseClicked` does represent. Although you could create your own click event with a combination of `ACTION_DOWN` `ACTION_UP` and some threshold of time and screen coordinates.

Comment: I followed a guide and have come with an attempt at it. However, in the emulator if I click with a mouse will it count it the same as a touch? If so, my `onTouch` isn't working. I currently have it as a method inside my View. Do I need to set it from my Activity instead?

Comment: I think now it's about time to see your Listener implementations and where you are using them in code.

Comment: updated it with my final question :) (sorry this has dragged on, I have been experimenting with code and reading a lot about touches and multiple touches)

Comment: I just ended up using `onTouchEvent` instead of `onTouch` which seemed to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

All touch events (down, up, move, multitouch) are handled via 'onTouch'. See this tutorial: http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-3-understanding-touch-events/1775

Comment: Ironically I was reading that article when I noticed I had a reply on SO. So if I understand it correctly, `ACTION_DOWN` is equivalent to `mouseClicked`, `ACTION_MOVE` is equivalent to `mousePressed`, and `ACTION_UP` is equivalent to `mouseReleased`?

Comment: Actually `ACTION_DOWN` equals `mousePressed` and `ACTION_MOVE`equals something like dragging.